# How to extract elements from a Table?

Tags: dataset, table, query, row

I have a time series table of three players

```
TimeTable = {
{{AA[1] -> 0.5, BB[1] -> 0.1, CC[1] -> 1}}[1],
{{AA[2] -> 1, BB[2] -> 0.5, CC[2] -> 2}}[2],
{{AA[3] -> 2, BB[3] -> 2, CC[3] -> 3}}[3],
{{AA[4] -> 3, BB[4] -> 3, CC[4] -> 4}}[4],
{{AA[5] -> 4, BB[5] -> 3, CC[5] -> 5}}[5]}
TimeTable[[5]]
```

I want to extract the last row and store the value of each element
`TimeTable[[5]]` yields `{{AA[5] -> 4, BB[5] -> 3, CC[5] -> 5}}[5]` I tried various methods including `Drop` and converting it into a  `Dataset` but it feels like there should a straight forward way to store it from the table.

I want to store the final values as `AA5 = 4; BB5 = 3;CC5 = 5`

Comment: There is formatting problem in `TimeTable`, please provide correctly formatted code for anyone to help you.

Comment: @PlatoManiac I have corrected it

Comment: The data format is completely unorthodox. Rows of the form `{rules...}[i]` are definitely not a normal thing. Where does this data come from and why does it have this format? What to you want to transform it into? What does it represent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your data looks really very **strange** for mathematica. But anyways getting a `Dataset` can be achieved like this.

```
TimeTableDT = Dataset@(Composition[Association, Head] /@ TimeTable)
```

Now you can get:
`TimeTableDT[5, Key@AA[5]]`

> 4

But you should check your data formatting. This is not at all a standard way of working with tabular data in mathematica, consult basic documentation on `List` and their friends.

Also setting values to symbols like `AA5=4` from your current data is another story.